# Swagger UI in EJBCA-CE not found

Tags: swagger-ui, ejbca

I've installed an EJBCA QuickStart container in a PoC context.

I launched successfully the web panel admin is accessible by using this URL : https://localhost:8443/ejbca/adminweb/

However, **I'm facing a 404 when I try to access the APIs definitions** : https://localhost:8443/ejbca/swagger-ui

[The documentation](https://doc.primekey.com/ejbca/ejbca-operations/ejbca-ca-concept-guide/protocols/ejbca-rest-interface#EJBCARESTInterface-SwaggerUIswagger) mentions this :

> The Swagger UI is only available if you build EJBCA in non-production mode, i.e. with ejbca.productionmode=false set in conf/ejbca.properties, and if REST is activated as a protocol (see below).

I've check this option was set correctly :

```bash
pki@localhost:~$ docker exec -it ejbca bash
bash-4.4$ cat ejbca/conf/ejbca.properties
#appserver.home=/opt/wildfly

ejbca.productionmode=false

# Allow override from /etc/ejbca/conf/
allow.external-dynamic.configuration=true

#------------------- EJBCA Healthcheck settings -------------
healthcheck.amountfreemem=16
healthcheck.dbquery=SELECT 1 FROM CertificateData WHERE fingerprint='XX'
healthcheck.authorizedips=ANY
healthcheck.catokensigntest=true
healthcheck.publisherconnections=false
healthcheck.maintenancefile=/etc/ejbca/conf/maintenance.properties
healthcheck.maintenancepropertyname=DOWN_FOR_MAINTENANCE
healthcheck.okmessage=ALLOK
healthcheck.customerrormessage=EJBCANOTOK
healthcheck.sendservererror=true

#------------------- CLI settings -------------
ejbca.cli.defaultusername=ejbca
ejbca.cli.defaultpassword=ejbca

# By default, EJBCA keeps a list of every EJBCA instance's hostname that has started in this cluster
# and allows for example Services to be pinned to a specific set of hostnames.
# In environments that has many short-lived instances with different hostnames this should be disabled.
#
# Default: true
ejbca.nodetracking=false
bash-4.4$
```

Also I activated both APIs v1 and v2 so I can use the APIs if I provided the good cert and key in my request :

```bash
toto@titi:~/PKI$ curl -k -X GET "https://localhost:8443/ejbca/ejbca-rest-api/v1/certificate/status" --cert api.crt --key api.key
{"status":"OK","version":"1.0","revision":"EJBCA 8.0 Community (ce7f5e74b9a054edf61b188fa46f03e57b8478ab)"}


toto@titi:~/PKI$ curl -k -X GET "https://localhost:8443/ejbca/ejbca-rest-api/v2/certificate/status" --cert api.crt --key api.key
{"status":"OK","version":"2.0","revision":"EJBCA 8.0 Community (ce7f5e74b9a054edf61b188fa46f03e57b8478ab)"}
```

It works, and it's running. I don't know why I can't access to the Swagger UI as mentioned in the documentation... Any idea ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swagger UI is a build-time component. It is not available in the container. To use the swagger-UI you need to install from source. Not ideal, agreed, but that's how it is at the moment.